# Remapping shifted function keys in XKB

Tags: gnome, keyboard, key-mapping, xkb

I'm working on a keyboard layout for the Khmer language and I'm quickly running out of space.  My aim is to create a keymap that includes all the characters in the Khmer script as well was their corresponding International Phonetic Alphabet characters.

I'd like to be able to remap the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd> key combinations to new Unicode code points, but currently it appears that these key combinations are reserved for system shortcuts.

How can I override this and remap these keys?

The layout I've made in XKB successfully remaps the unmodified <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys, but <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F*n*</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F*n*</kbd>, etc. are treated the same as if I pressed the <kbd>F*n*</kbd> key by itself.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Cross posting is a reason to close a question. You probably should remove it on one of the sites.

Comment: Ok, my mistake.  I thought cross-posting was acceptable as long as a link to the other discussion is posted.  I will keep the question here, and remove it from the Ubuntu Stack Exchange.

Comment: Have you looked at what Fn generates with `xev`? I have a different behaviour (via .Xmodmap) for the left and right Alt key, maybe that would help expand your map as well.

Comment: You need to make sure to change the keysym and not just add the character. I don't know how this is expressed with XKB. Also be sure to relaunch the applications that provide the shortcuts, I think grabs can survive remappings.